# Testing something that requires dynamic pageloads using Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I'm trying to create a test for a quiz. The quiz works like this:

1. Click and wait on the quiz link.
2. First page has a question and radio buttons. User clicks on a radio button, then clicks and waits on the submit button.
3. Second page is another question with radio buttons. User clicks on a radio button, then clicks and waits on the submit button, etc.
4. After N pages, at the results page, I want to verify that some text exists.

The purposes of this test are: (1) that the user can take a quiz all the way to the end, (2) quiz questions are submitting properly (no exceptions between submissions), (3) the user sees the expected results.

I know that I can do this easily with Selenium RC, but I need this is in Selenium IDE so that non-technical people can just press a button when they are doing a smoke test. (I know, QA is supposed to do this, but I don't make the rules.)

My question is: how should I best test a quiz with a dynamic number of questions (quizzes featured on our quiz page vary from day to day and some get disabled or deleted from the system)?

I'm looking to do this in JavaScript (putting the script in runScript), but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of "clickAndWait" within the script, so I can't do a submit.

I'm new to JavaScript, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[blog post](http://brettweiss.wordpress.com/2009/09/25/perform-while-loop-in-the-selenium-ide/) describing about the same thing...